# Why frattini sub group is important?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group and denote its Frattini subgroup by Φ(G). I know that Φ(G) is the intersection of the maximal subgroups of G, and I know that it is the set of 'non-generators'

Can we compute frattini sub group for any group ? For example we can find frattini sub group for any cyclic group .
What is history of frattini subgroup ?
Why frattini sub group is important?

Answer (score 3):

There is no short answer for all your questions. Can one compute the Frattini subgroup? Yes, there are algorithms for doing it. I will not go into detail, but just give a reference by [Bettina Eick](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick/publ/special.ps). For cyclic groups one should know the Frattini subgroup.
For example, $\Phi(C_p)=1$ for primes $p$ and $\Phi(C_{p^a})\cong C_{p^{a-1}}$.
Other examples examples are: 
$$
\Phi(S_n)=1,\; \Phi(D_n)=1,\; \Phi (C_{p} \wr C_{p})\cong [C_{p} \wr C_{p},C_{p} \wr C_{p}]
$$

Why are Fratini groups important? See the following references:

[Intuition behind the Frattini subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329964/intuition-behind-the-frattini-subgroup?rq=1)

[Some questions on the Frattini subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70835/some-questions-on-the-frattini-subgroup?rq=1)

[Does every finite nilpotent group occur as a Frattini subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717619/does-every-finite-nilpotent-group-occur-as-a-frattini-subgroup/717774#717774)

Comment: Can you give more details of the reference by Bettina Eick. I am not able to open the link you attached. Thanks!

Comment: @Jins I can still open it. The title is "
Special Presentations for Finite Soluble Groups and Computing (Pre)-Frattini Subgroups". You can google this for different links, e.g., [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717104000720).

Comment: Thanks, Dietrich Burde. I didnt get how the paper by Bettina Eick et al.  presented algorithm for finding Frattini subgroup ? Is there any efficient algorithm known to find Frattini subgroup for general group ? or some special groups ?